# Angularjs with JSP

Tags: angularjs, jsp, model-view-controller

I am developing a new webapp in which we are primarily using JSP to generate static UI components. The Angular routing is bound to JSP instead of html templates.

A quick search in Google always discourages using Angular with server side MVCs, but I havent been able to find a convincing reason enough on why we should not do it. Can someone explain , what is the issue with using server side MVC with client side MVC.

Answer (score 0):

Why should you repeat a task in server and client side? like maintaining the state of the application..

I could thing of a case where jsp(any template engine) with angular will be helpful,
where you want to localize your text intensive application. 
You can localize angular templates in the server side, let it take a page refresh.

Comment: The reason we could not get away with the JSP is because all our static UI components are built using the JSP markup which cannot be avoided.

Comment: When you think of building client app using Angular js, you will have to start from scratch..